# Modify data if it contains hyphen in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm not sure how to start to search the answer on my question. cant find the right words. If you can point me to the right direction, it will be great.

Basically, my problem is.
I have a source value example is 929-123-12-1111,
but it also contains value 123---, if the value is 123--- what I like to do is update/change it to 123-000-00-0000.

Is this possible to do in the select statement?

select numcode from table

Comment: Is 123-454-- a valid input? Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: im using sqlserver 2008. if the source is value is 123-454--, i want to change it to 123-454-00-0000

Comment: this is not solution `SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@S,5,0,'000'),9,0,'00')+'0000'` you could do some thing likr this

Comment: Is it possible to skip sections and still be valid, i.e. 123--22- ? Or does the section left of the hyphen need to be populated for the section right of the hyphen to be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all hyphen, pad it with 0 and recompose result like `SUBSTRING(1, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(4, 3) + '-'`...

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT *, REPLACE(Id, '-', '') AS IdNoHyphen
    FROM (VALUES ('929-123-12-1111'), ('123---'), ('123-456--')) AS T(Id)
),
T2 AS
(
    SELECT *, LEFT(IdNoHyphen + '00000000000', 12) AS Padded
    FROM T1
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(Padded, 1, 3) + '-' 
    +  SUBSTRING(Padded, 4, 3) + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(Padded, 7, 2) + '-' 
    + SUBSTRING(Padded, 9, 4)
FROM T2
```

Comment: Thank you qxg, but this might be a problem. I will be updating an existing view in my company. So I dont think I can to the REPLACE part. Can I do the replace and padded on one select?